# array program to store a certain value from one array to another giving wrong output while running the below code in java

Tags: java, arrays, exception, store, indexoutofboundsexception

package Starter_Code;

public class Solution {

```
public int[] checkNumber(int[] inIntArr1,int[] inIntArr2) {
    int[] outIntArr=new int[inIntArr1.length];
    int temp,pro=1;
    
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<inIntArr1.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<inIntArr2.length;j++){
            if(inIntArr1[i]==inIntArr2[j]){
                outIntArr[k]=inIntArr1[i];
                k++;
                break;
            }else if(Math.pow(inIntArr1[i], 2)==inIntArr2[j]){
                outIntArr[k]=inIntArr1[i];
                k++;
                break;
                
            }else if(inIntArr1[inIntArr1.length-1]==inIntArr2[inIntArr2.length-1]){
                outIntArr[k]=inIntArr1[i];
                k++;
                break;
            }else{
            
                while(inIntArr1[i]>0){
                temp=(inIntArr1[i])%10;
                pro=pro*temp;
                inIntArr1[i]=inIntArr1[i]/10;
                }
                if(pro==inIntArr2[j]){
                    outIntArr[k]=inIntArr1[i];
                    k++;
                    break;
                }
                
            }
            
            
         }
    }

    return outIntArr;
}
```

}

package Starter_Code;

public class Tester {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[] inIntArr1= {26,17,25,35,39,63};
    int[] inIntArr2= {26,671,11,21,14,28};
  //Create an object of Solution
    Solution sol = new Solution();
    
    //Call checkNumber()
    int[]  result = sol.checkNumber(inIntArr1, inIntArr2);
    
    //display the output 
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

}

in this code i have to store the vales of inIntarr1 to outIntArr based on the condition which i have given in if statement and the length of outIntArr should be with in the range of inIntArr1, but the output is something like this [I@7a8ce1e1

Comment: `i < inIntArr1.length` otherwise i being 7 would still loop (i < 63).

Comment: hi @JoopEggen thank you for your suggestion....i changed the code but now i am getting wrong output !! could you tell how to resolve this?

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the lines, seeing what is done. That most helps to find mistakes. `Math.pow(inIntArr1[i], 2)` can be done with integral arithmetic. If 63 is the highest argument, `1L << inIntArr1[2]` (64 bits signed long). Floating point pow is imprecise. Another tip: **format** your code; the IDE provides such an entry, and every (?) developer formats code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing directly an array will give you the hashcode always.
change your code like below and will get the readable format output.

**Current code**:

//display the output

```
System.out.println(result);
```

**Suggested code**:
**Try this**

// display the output

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Comment: but after changing this , there is a compilation erorr stating "arrays cannot be resolved" why is that and what to do

Comment: Add this line at the top in the imports section(below package statement)   **import java.util.Arrays;**

Answer (score 0):

The array does't contain a number less than it length (i < inIntArr1) and therefore an error is thrown.